# Pyspark java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aliyun/oss/ServiceException

Tags: pyspark, open-source, alibaba-cloud

Pyspark with Aliyun's prebuild SDK doesn't seem to work.

Env:

- Apache Spark 2.2.0 on virtual machine
- OSS which is created under same user account
- Tokyo Region (ap-northeast-1)

This is my snippet for reproduce symptom.

Command:

```
/opt/spark/bin/pyspark --master="mesos://${MASTER}" --executor-memory 12g --jars /home/admin/aliyun-emapreduce-sdk/prebuild/emr-core-1.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar,/home/admin/aliyun-emapreduce-sdk/prebuild/emr-sdk_2.10-1.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar --conf "spark.hadoop.fs.oss.impl"="com.aliyun.fs.oss.nat.NativeOssFileSystem"
```

PySpark code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.oss.impl", "com.aliyun.fs.oss.nat.NativeOssFileSystem")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "12g")
conf.set("spark.python.worker.memory", "8g")
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

# read from local hdfs
df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://10.1.185.28:9000/User/admin/nyc/yellow.parquet")
# [failed] write to Aliyun OSS
outPathBase = "oss://MyOSSID:MySecretKey@oss-ap-northeast-1-internal.aliyuncs.com/test"
df.write.parquet(outPathBase+"/yellow.parquet")
```

Here is error like this.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o74.parquet.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aliyun/oss/ServiceException
    at com.aliyun.fs.oss.nat.JetOssNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(JetOssNativeFileSystemStore.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at 
(snip)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aliyun.oss.ServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Any advice ?

Comment: Which region? Which service (E-mapReduce or MaxCompute)? Where did you get the syntax  for "oss://MyOSSID:MySecretKey@oss-ap-northeast-1-internal.aliyuncs.com/test"?

Comment: I am assuming E-MapReduce for this question. Did you create an application role for E-MapReduce? There is a predefined role "AliyunEmrEcsDefaultRole" which will provide EMR with write permissions to OSS. In my prevous question, the OSS line that you specified is for the HDFS tool. You will use normal syntax such as "oss://mybucket/path/file" AND a RAM application role. Look into E-MapReduce MetaService. https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/43966.htm

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've deployed original Spark in VM. Japan (ap-northeast-1) region. My syntax comes from https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-spark-sdk .

Comment: and https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/28118.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.116.53067e8fNtVuQN .

Comment: OK I see the syntax that you are using. I always use RAM roles and never put access keys into the source code. Look at the endpoint that you are using. You are using the Intranet endpoint for data transfers within the same region. I think that you will need to use the Internet endpoint unless both the E-MapReduce instance and OSS bucket are in the same region but try the change even if they are in the same region. Does your access key have OSS permissions to write? Also it looks like the SDK is not including the class for the OSS exception: com.aliyun.oss.ServiceException

Comment: I just realized that you updated your post with new information. Everything I said above is for E-MapReduce. I did not realize that you are using your own ECS instance for EMR / Spark. I am not sure if that will make a difference regarding permissions, but I have not built my own EMR setup on ECS.